# Setting Hadoop Config properties for Spark 2.x SQLContexts

Tags: apache-spark

Spark 2.x here. I need to set the following Hadoop configurations so that my `SqlContext` can talk to S3:

```
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "blah1")
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "blah 2")
```

However it seems that as of 2.x, `SparkContext` and `SqlContext` are two separate objects that are built from a `SparkSession`:

```
val sparkContext = SparkSession.builder().appName("myapp").getOrCreate().sparkContext
val sqlContext = SparkSession.builder().appName("myapp").getOrCreate().sqlContext
```

**So how do I set the `sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration` properties for the `SQLContext` if the `SQLContext` is totally separate from the `SparkContext`?!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the SQLContext is totally separate from the SparkContext?!

Neither `SparkSession` nor `SQLContext` are separate from `SparkContext`. Both are tightly bound to a specific `SparkContext` instance. Also you shouldn't need `SQLContext` for anything else than legacy applications, when using Spark 2.x. For everything else `SparkSession` provides equivalent interface.

Just initialize `SparkSession`

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("myapp").getOrCreate()
```

and use its context to set Hadoop configuration

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "blah1")
```

In your code setting configuration on `sparkContext` would work as well. Each Spark application can have only one `SparkContext` and it is reused each time you call `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate`, or even if you create `newSession`.

Comment: Thanks @user9613318 (+1) but I might disagree about your statement about not needing to use `sqlContxt` in 2.x. I'm trying to use the Spark Redshift driver and [their docs](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift#scala) clearly show the need to use `sqlContext.read`, or are you saying there's a new + improved way of doing this? Thanks again!

Comment: I am saying that `spark.read` will work the same, and should be preferred. Redshift connector just hasn't been actively maintained in a while, so docs are still reflecting 1.x state,